# Comparing the sizes of null sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, logic, descriptive-set-theory, infinite-games

This question is about comparing the relative sizes of null sets by switching from open covers to open cover*ing* *sequences* (a la [strong measure zero sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_measure_zero_set) or [microscopic sets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04424.pdf)). The main question is whether the most obvious preorder is in fact linear, and the secondary question is whether this preorder coincides with a related "game-theoretic" preorder I know is linear.

Below we either work in $\mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{DC}+\mathsf{AD_\mathbb{R}}$ or restrict attention to appropriately tame sets of reals.

---

### Main question

For $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ of measure zero, say that the **efficiency** of $X$ is the set $\mathsf{Eff}(X)$ of all sequences of positive reals $\alpha=(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that there is some sequence of nonempty rational open intervals $(U_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $m(U_i)\le a_i$ for each $i$ and $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}U_i\supseteq X$.

We get a natural preorder from this notion, $\trianglelefteq$, via $$X\trianglelefteq Y\iff \mathsf{Eff}(X)\supseteq\mathsf{Eff}(Y)$$ (that's not a typo - the idea is that $X\trianglelefteq Y$ means that $X$ is *smaller* than $Y$, which is to say that it's *more* efficient). I would like to understand this preorder better, and in particular:

> Is $\trianglelefteq$ a *linear* preorder?

---

### Secondary question

There is a different relation, of similar "flavor" to $\trianglelefteq$, which I *can* prove is a linear preorder. Namely, given null $X,Y$ consider the game $E(X,Y)$ defined as follows:

- Players $1$ and $2$ alternately play individual nonempty rational open intervals building a sequence $U_0,V_0,U_1,V_1,...$, with $m(U_i)\ge m(V_i)\ge m(U_{i+1})$.
- Player $1$ wins a given play iff

  - for each $n$ we have $\bigcup_{i>n}U_i\supseteq Y$, but
  - there is some $n$ such that $\bigcup_{i>n}V_i\not\supseteq X$.

*(The win condition can be rephrased as a kind of **redundancy** property: "$(U_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ covers $X$ with infinite repetition but $(V_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not cover $Y$ with infinite repetition.")*

Consider the relation $\sqsubseteq$ given by $$X\sqsubseteq Y\iff \mbox{player $2$ has a winning strategy in $E(X,Y)$}.$$

Like $\trianglelefteq$ this is clearly reflexive and transitive, and linearity follows from determinacy. If $X\not\sqsubseteq Y$ then player $1$ has a winning strategy $\Sigma$ in $E(X,Y)$, and we can turn that into a winning strategy $\hat{\Sigma}$ for player $2$ in $E(Y,X)$. This is where the redundancy part of the win condition comes in: $\hat{\Sigma}$'s first move will be essentially useless, but this won't affect the ultimate outcome.

So one natural way to get a positive answer to the main question would be to prove $\sqsubseteq$ is the same as $\trianglelefteq$. However, I don't see how to do this:

> Do $\trianglelefteq$ and $\sqsubseteq$ coincide?

I suspect that the answer is no, and in fact that $\trianglelefteq$ is not linear.

*(As an aside, the "non-redundant-covering" version of $\sqsubseteq$ is more similar to $\trianglelefteq$ so would make the secondary question more interesting, but I don't know that that relation is linear either so it's not obviously useful to the main question.)*

Comment: Incidentally, I've asked a couple questions at MO which generated discussion that might be relevant (although at the moment I don't see it): [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219311/two-strengthenings-of-strong-measure-zero?rq=1), [2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/220687/8133).

Comment: Besides the Cantor set, do you please ( is there any ) say a set which its measure is zero but not strongly?

Comment: @MaryamAjorlou [It's consistent](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485889934) with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that **no** uncountable measure-zero set is strong measure zero. On the other hand, the Cantor set is paradigmatic in the context of this question since every "tame" uncountable set has a perfect subset.

Comment: Noah, does AD (or its variants) prove that every strong measure zero set is countable?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think perfect sets don't have strong measure zero, so yes?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, it was a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two closed measure zero sets $A$ and $B$ which are incomparable under $\trianglelefteq$.

Let $A$ be the Cantor set.

Let $B=C\cup D$ where $C$ and $D$ are nonempty perfect measure zero sets with $\operatorname{diam}(C)\lt\frac14$, $\operatorname{diam}(D)\lt\frac1{10}$, and $d(C,D)\gt2$.

Let $\varepsilon=(\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3,\dots)$ be a sequence of positive rational numbers such that $\varepsilon\notin\mathsf{Eff}(C)\cup\mathsf{Eff}(D)$.

Then
$$(2,\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3,\dots)\in\mathsf{Eff}(A)\setminus\mathsf{Eff}(B)$$
while
$$\left(\frac14,\frac1{10},\frac1{28},\cdots,\frac1{3^n+1},\cdots\right)\in\mathsf{Eff}(B)\setminus\mathsf{Eff}(A).$$

Regarding the game $E(X,Y)$ it should be noted that the existence of a winning strategy for player $1$ implies that $X$ is "strategically strong measure zero" and therefore countable as shown in [Andreas Blass](https://mathoverflow.net/users/6794/andreas-blass)'s answer to the question [Two strengthenings of "strong measure zero"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219311/two-strengthenings-of-strong-measure-zero).